# How to create one scatterplot in Excel with 4 outcome categories from 3 groups of people?

Tags: excel, graph, charts, scatter-plot

This is kind of hard to explain but here's my question. Basically, I have 3 groups of people and 4 categories that those people can be sorted into. I want to show all 3 groups on one scatterplot and differentiate between the groups by changing the marker shape (ex group 1=circle, group 2=triangle, group 3=square) and then show the outcome category they were sorted into by the color (cat 1=red, cat 2=blue, cat 3=purple, cat 4=green).

I'm really struggling with how to make this into one single scatterplot. If it helps, here's a subset of my data:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6ZT4.png)

I have the colors labeled on the top for what each (x,y) point should be colored. The row below the colors are labels for the numbers that comprise the outcome categories, so for example 0.682571 from the C_HR_SC column and 0.007571 from the C_HR_SR column should create a RED marker that will say something like "High risk" in the legend. There will be 4 of these categories created by the 8 columns in the data since each point has an x and y. And then this subset includes data from 3 groups so I need to somehow differentiate that by changing the marker shapes within the series.

Hopefully I've explained well enough what I need help with? Any guidance would be appreciated, thank you!

This is an example of what a scatterplot of only 1 group should look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36KYS.png)

So I need to add 2 more groups to this graph and then differentiate between the groups by changing the marker shape. Struggling on how to do this without creating more series, like I've tried just selecting new data from the 2nd group and adding that to the graph, but it shows up on the legend like a new outcome category and it's not. It should be included within the original 4 outcome categories.

Comment: Well, make 3 scatter plots and then make 2 transparent and lay them on top as overlays...

Comment: that's clever I might try that lol thanks!!

Comment: You may need to define the start & end values of the axes... Or, you could scale the readings to separate the groups.

Comment: I ended up using your idea and it worked out, had to scale the axes so they matched up like you said and it looks great. I love a loophole! Thanks!